# Incorrect frame size inside UITextfield Subclass in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8

Upgrading Xcode version to 8, I've found tons of problem that I'm still fixing almost my swift2.3 version to swift3. One of my problem is all custom UITextfield does not work at all as displaying blank in my project. Following is my custom UITextfield and how to fix to be displayed correctly in swift3.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class OvalTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        createBorder()
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let finalString = textField.text! + string;
        if (finalString != "") {
            textField.rightView?.isHidden = true
        }
        return true
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createBorder()
    }

    func createBorder(){

        let errorImg = UIImageView (frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        errorImg.image = UIImage(named: "error")
        errorImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.left

        self.delegate = self
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.93, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

        let gapLabel = UIView (frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 0, width: 20, height: 40))
        self.leftView = gapLabel
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always

        /* Display that one when validation is failed */
        self.rightView = errorImg;
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    }
}
```

Comment: `let ovTxtFld = OvalTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 200, height: 20))
        self.view.addSubview(ovTxtFld)`

Comment: I've added that custom UITextfield in storyboard thus above code is not required at all.

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: I've already configured and put that custom UITextfield in my storyboard. I've added screenshot in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextField` is getting it's frame from the storyboard so you are getting incorrect frame size while setting cornerRadius.

You have error while setting the corner radius.

```
 self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
```

Replace this with

`self.layer.cornerRadius = 2`

Or also better if you override `drawRect` method and set cornerRadius as

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

     self.layer.cornerRadius = rect.size.height / 2

}
```